# Debugging main process in an electron app when using electron-forge

Tags: debugging, webstorm, electron, electron-forge

I'm attempting to debug the main process of my electron app according to 
this https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/

I've set up everything as described, but am getting an error when attempting to debug.

> /Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/cli.js --debug-brk=56546 --expose_debug_as=v8debug /Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/src/index.js
>   App threw an error during load
>   Error: Cannot find module '/Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/--debug-brk=56546'
>       at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
>       at init (/Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/node_modules/electron-compile/lib/config-parser.js:279:16)
>       at main (/Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:38:29)
>       at Object. (/Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:41:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:473:32)

I've made sure all the settings are correct. Could be because I'm using electron-forge or does it not have anything to do with it?

Comment: weird - for some reason the option is appended to module path (`/Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/--debug-brk=56546`), though the command looks OK. Can you try running just the same command (`/Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/cli.js --debug-brk=56546 --expose_debug_as=v8debug /Users/robertferentz/Work/connect-admin/src/index.js`) in your system terminal?

Comment: This happened to me when I started using electron-forge. Prior to that it worked fine. But after adding electron forge, the node interpreter in the run/debug configuration switches from node_modules/.bin/electron to node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/cli.js, and there doesn't seem to be a way to change that while still using electron-forge.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with `electron-prebuilt-compile` - see https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt-compile/issues/23.
Please try using `electron-prebuilt` instead

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Setting up the run/debug configuration in Webstorm, selecting Project/node_modules/.bin/electron for the node interpreter automatically switches to Project/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/cli.js I've tried setting it multiple times, always switches to that. So basically, if we want to use electron-forge or electron-compile, debugging will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

In package.json:

```
electron-forge start -- %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION%
```

and running task in debug works fine.